# Same-origin policy and location property

Tags: html

I have a simple test page:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" id="ifrm" style="height: 100px"></iframe>

...

<script>
document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() {
  try {             
    alert(frames[0].location);          // 1.
    console.log(frames[0].location);    // 2.
    var loc = frames[0].location;       // 3.
    alert(loc);                         // 4.
  } 
  catch (e) {
    alert("Error: " + e)
  }
}
</script>
```

According to the "Same-origin policy" - "it is not allowed to read from another origin" so why does the line #1 cause an exception while #2 isn't?
Why does the line #3 is legal while #4 isn't? Doesn't we access remote location property just in #3?

Answer (score 0):

> why does the line #2 cause an exception while #1 isn't?

You have that backwards. Line 1 throws an exception, line 2 does not.

---

The `location` object itself is allowed to be accessed, but certain properties on it are not.

Passing it to `console.log()` passes the entire thing to the developer tools (where it is out of reach of the untrusted JS).

Passing it to `alert()` implicitly tries to convert it to a string, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thx. for reply. Yes, sorry i indeed muddled the lines up. But what about the lines #3 and #4? Am i right that assigning the location object to variable is allowed so the line #3 is OK but outputting it in #4 line like in line #1 is forbidden?

Comment: @MulliGan81 — Line 3: "The location object itself is allowed to be accessed, but certain properties on it are not." — You are just accessing the location object itself. Which is fine.

Comment: @MulliGan81 — Line 4: "Passing it to alert() implicitly tries to convert it to a string, which is not allowed."